# remote Webtest script using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm working on an powershell script to test websites on remote computers.
The script is working well on available websites but I have issue on unavailable website.

```
$HTTP_Request1 = Invoke-command -ComputerName SGEDEEWOSWEBP10  -Scriptblock{Invoke-WebRequest -Method HEAD -Uri www.google.com -UseBasicParsing }

$HTTP_Status1 = $HTTP_Request1.StatusCode
echo $HTTP_Status1
```

With google or any authorized website it's working well, the HTTP code is equal to 200.
But when I put an unauthorized website like www.guns.com who is blocked by a network equipment i don't have an HTTP code but an error instead.

error :

```
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
    + PSComputerName        : server name
```

The website is blocked (normal) so I should have a 403 HTTP code.

```
URL                     Protocol   Method   Result  
http://www.guns.com/    HTTP       GET      403
```

With IE locally on the server.

```
Web Page Blocked!
You have tried to access a web page which is in violation of your internet usage policy.

URL: http://www.guns.com/
Category: Weapons (Sales) 
User name: 
Group name:

To have the rating of this web page re-evaluated please click here.
```

could someone help me to have the http code of the rejected URL ?

thanks.
Julien

Answer (score 0):

Add a try-catch block, and handle the error in the catch. If a response was returned you can get the status code like this:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

try
{
    $httpRequest = Invoke-command -ComputerName "SGEDEEWOSWEBP10" -Scriptblock { Invoke-WebRequest -Method HEAD -Uri "www.google.com" -UseBasicParsing }
    $httpStatus  = $httpRequest.StatusCode
}
catch
{
    $httpStatus = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__
}

Write-Host $httpStatus
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback, I tried but unfortunately it's not working.

The catch doesn't detect the error.

```
try { $HTTP_Request2 = Invoke-command -ComputerName $IPAddress -Scriptblock{Invoke-WebRequest -Method HEAD -Uri www.guns.com -UseBasicParsing }
$HTTP_Status2 = $HTTP_Request2.StatusCode echo $HTTP_Status2 } 
catch { 
$HTTP_Status2 = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ 
echo ko 
      } 
echo $HTTP_Status2
```

I have the same result and the "ko" isn't display.